# Raspberry Pi4 vs 4B--synonymous?

Tags: hardware, pi-4, poe

I am embarking on a cluster project using PoE hat.  PoE hat is compatible with RPI4B.  Vendor is selling "Raspberry Pi4."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications shows only 4B, so I assume they're synonymous, and I'm safe to go with the "4" and the PoE hat together.  Is this assumption accurate?

I just don't want to invest in hats and PoE switch if there is a compatibility question.

Thanks.

Comment: there is only `B` series in the Pi 4 family - the `A` series is a different (smaller) form factor (physical layout)

Comment: There's three models of RPi4 (aka RPi4B) -  the 1GB, 2GB and 4GB. Cheapest (and best for a beginner) is the RPi4B1GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pi 4 and Pi 4B are synonymous - for now.  As per your Wikipedia page, sometimes they have released 'A' versions of Pi boards (1A, 1A+, 3A+), which are smaller, a bit less power hungry, and lacking Ethernet socket.  Someone ever selling a Pi 4A should almost certainly make that fact obvious. Also if yours has an Ethernet socket, its a 'B'.

You can see the currently available Pis here - https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/